# Azure Service Bus topic - subscription message expiry

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus

I'm using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus namespace to connect to a Service Bus topic. I'm looking for a way to retrieve messages from a subscription iteratively as it was possible using the Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging namespace? I'm looking for something similar:

```
SubscriptionClient subscriptionClient = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ServiceBusConnectionString, TopicName, SubscriptionName);

while(true)
{
    BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = subscriptionClient.ReceiveAsync().Result;
    var strBody = brokeredMessage.GetBody<Stream>();
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(strBody);
    Console.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
    brokeredMessage.Complete();
}
```

AFAIK, `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` library provides the only option of using `subscriptionClient.RegisterMessageHandler` which uses the underlying Message Pump.

However, in the event of an outage at the subscriber application and if it needs to read the pending unread messages from the Subscription, it needs to do a `Receive` or `ReceiveAsync`

Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 0):

Messages can be received from queue/subscription using one of the two methods.

1. Manually using `Receive()`/`ReceiveAsync()` provided by `MessageReceiver` or
2. Automatically using message pump provided by `QueueClient`/`SubscriptionClient`

Behind the scenes, message pump (aka Message Handler) is using the manual option to receive messages.